# ModelForms in Django with Bootstrap

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I can see that you can use django-bootstrap-toolkit to generate bootstrap forms in Django. This looks pretty cool. However I have 2 questions,

- Can django-bootstrap-toolkit be used also for modelforms ?
- If I had a large form that is created with django-bootstrap-toolkit what would
  be the best method for me to pass the form to the template for it to
  automatically render whilst allowing me to place sections of text
  (i.e headers throughout the form) ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Maybe [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) helps you.

Example (Maybe that works):

```
class Foo(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    date = models.DateField(...)

class FooForm(ModelForm):
    model = Foo
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'name': BootstrapTextInput(prepend='P'),
        }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> Can django-bootstrap-toolkit be used also for modelforms ?

Presumably, yes. Looks like django-bootstrap-toolkit provides some specific widgets and also styles forms/form fields (using Bootstrap). Apart from that, the forms seem to be just plain Django forms (`forms.Form`).

> If I had a large form that is created with django-bootstrap-toolkit what would be the best method for me to pass the form to the template for it to automatically render whilst allowing me to place sections of text (i.e headers throughout the form) ?

You can [customise your form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template), but I don't think is what you meant by 'automatically render'.

You *could* also use JavaScript to inject some headings and manipulate HTML in general, but this is not recommended (due to tight coupling, accessibility and maintainability and other factors).

Overall, I'm not sure how customisable the layouts django-bootstrap-toolkit from code. You might like to check out [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which has layouts framework (including fieldsets for headings) and support for Bootstrap.